# iss claim is not valid Keycloak

Tags: angular, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm using Spring Boot, Angular and Keycloak are dockerized in own containers in same network.

The `issuer-uri` in spring-boot backend is `http://keycloak:8080/realms/sales` and the
*iss* from decoded *JWT* token is `http://localhost:8082/realms/sales`.

**Problem**: My browser cannot use docker network hostnames. I have to use localhost to access keycloak.

I tried `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` and other env variables, but did not fix my problem.

Anyone know how to make *iss* on both the same in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical problem when moving from your pc - all localhost services - to dockerized environment.

The best and correct approach is to get a domain name for your keycloak instance and refer to the auth url as `https://mykeycloak.something.com` so the issuer is always this.

Another approach, but similar is to refer by the IP of the machine, so something like `http://192.168.x.x:8082/realms/sales`

EDIT: you should not go to production with a machine IP as issuer...